# Python commands to build distribution setup.py build vs python -m build

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I'm learning about Python packaging, and according to this [guide](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#packaging-your-project), the command to build a python distribution package seems to be `python3 -m build`.

But I aslo found that there is a command line interface for setup.py file from setuptools:

```sh
$ python setup.py --help-commands
Standard commands:
  build             build everything needed to install
  sdist             create a source distribution (tarball, zip file, etc.)
  bdist             create a built (binary) distribution
  bdist_dumb        create a "dumb" built distribution
  bdist_rpm         create an RPM distribution
  ...
```

It seems that `python setup.py build`, `sdist` or `bdist` can aslo build distribution, but I didn't find detailed intructions for these commands, the [setuptools command reference](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/commands.html) lacks explanation for `build` `sdist` `bdist`.

So I'm a bit confused, what is the difference between `python setup.py build` and `python -m build`, or between `python setup.py sdist` and `python -m build --sdist`? Is the `python setup.py` command deprecated hence the lack of full documentation? When should I use `python -m build` or `python setup.py build`?

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Update:
The [doc](https://pypa-build.readthedocs.io/en/stable/differences.html#setup-py-sdist-bdist-wheel) of `build` module says “build is roughly the equivalent of `setup.py sdist bdist_wheel` but with PEP 517 support, allowing use with projects that don’t use setuptools”.

So should I always prefer build module rather than running python setup.py manually?. Is there still a use-case for `setup.py build`?

Comment: `python setup.py` runs the file. `python -m build` uses the `build` module (which may in-turn read a setup.py file, if it exists)

Comment: @OneCricketeer The [doc](https://pypa-build.readthedocs.io/en/stable/differences.html#setup-py-sdist-bdist-wheel) of build module says build is roughly the equivalent of `setup.py sdist bdist_wheel` but with PEP 517 support, allowing use with projects that don’t use setuptools. So should I always prefer build module rather than running `python setup.py` manually? Is there still a use-case for `setup.py build`?

Comment: I'm not really sure.  I've only used Poetry for packaging

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Citing [Why you shouldn't invoke setup.py directly](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html) by Paul Ganssle.

- The setuptools project has stopped maintaining all direct invocations
  of setup.py years ago, and distutils is deprecated.
- There are
  undoubtedly many ways that your setup.py-based system is broken
  today, even if it's not failing loudly or obviously.
- Direct
  invocations of setup.py cannot bootstrap their own dependencies, and
  so some CLI is necessary for dependency management.
- The setuptools
  project no longer wants to provide any public CLI, and will be
  actively removing the existing interface (though the time scale for
  this is long).
- PEP 517, 518 and other standards-based packaging are
  the future of the Python ecosystem and a lot of progress has been
  made on making this upgrade seamless.

Here's a summary table of the `setup.py` way and the newer recommended method:

| setup.py | New command |
| --- | --- |
| setup.py sdist | python -m build (with [build](https://pypa-build.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)) |
| setup.py bdist_wheel | python -m build (with [build](https://pypa-build.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)) |
| setup.py test | pytest (usually via [tox](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/) or [nox](https://nox.thea.codes/en/stable/index.html)) |
| setup.py install | pip install |
| setup.py develop | pip install -e |
| setup.py upload | twine upload (with [twine](https://twine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) |
| setup.py check | twine check (this doesn't do all the same checks but it's a start) |
| Custom commands | [tox](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/) and [nox](https://nox.thea.codes/en/stable/index.html) environments. |